# Robust way to render unique order number

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency

Please see the code below to generate an unique ascending number from a base number stored in a row of a parameter table. I wonder if this is a safe way to prevent concurrent use of the same number.

My knowledge of concurrency in SQL server is limited so I hope that there are some experts here to give me some advice if this code prevents concurrent use of the same number. Any help or thoughts are highly appreciated.

```
/* Create table to store temporary value */
declare @bedrijf_parameter_voor_update table (bedrijf_parameter_id id, afleverbon_start_nr int)

/* Raise counter by 1 */
update bedrijf_parameter
set afleverbon_start_nr = afleverbon_start_nr + 1

/* Store deleted row to use as order number */
output deleted.bedrijf_parameter_id, deleted.afleverbon_start_nr into @bedrijf_parameter_voor_update
where bedrijf_parameter_id = 1 --there is only one row in bedrijfs_parameter which holds all the parameters of the application 

/* Write the order number to the transport table */
update transport
set vracht_bon_nummer = (select afleverbon_start_nr from @bedrijf_parameter_voor_update where bedrijf_parameter_id = 1)
where transport_id = @transport_id and vracht_bon_nummer is null
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an `identity` column? Because then SQL Server does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @DaleK: That would be a good option indeed, however then I will have to change a lot of existing structure in my application, which will probably lead to a chainreaction of changes. I also wanted to use a UNIQUE constraint on the column of the transport table as additional (final) security, but the framework I am using doesn't yet allow me to exclude NULLs. Future version will and then I will definitely be using a UNIQUE constraint on the column.